# Call method from another file as string in Java

Tags: java, string, import

I have file `ClassifierModule.java` with following method:

```
public class ClassifierModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements BufferListener {

    public int measureRatio(double[] means) {
        return (int) (means[3] / means[1]) ;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call this method to create a `String` in another .java file like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int r = ClassifierModule.measureRatio(double[]);
}
```

The only result I get is an error:

```
error: '.class' expected:
int r = ClassifierModule.measureRatio(double[]);
                                              ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the fuul code of ClassifierModule.java -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M6UlRkGEduBxQIsuOz93HEMGPtI8NiB9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you try to call an instance method in a static context, for one. also, as parameter, you need to pass a variable with a value, not a type

Comment: What are you trying to do at `int r = ClassifierModule.measureRatio(double[]);`? You claim that "to create string in another .java file" but I don't see any String here. Use [edit] option to clarify your question. Describe what you expect from that code.

Comment: Pshemo, I want to save "public int measureRatio(double[] means)" to string in another file, but I don't know how to call it.

Comment: I honestly suggest that you spend some time reading basic tutorials from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ ... top to bottom. You seem to be rather inventing your own syntax here. Your code simply doesn't make sense on various levels.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ClassifierModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements BufferListener {

    public int measureRatio(double[] means){
        return (int) (means[3] / means[1]) ;
    }
}
```

`measureRatio` is an instance method, so it can't be called through the class, but must be called through an instance of the class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int r = ClassifierModule.measureRatio(double[]);
}
```

`double[]` is the type which you have to pass, but it's not a value the method can work with. Change it to something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  double[] param = new double[5];
  param[0] = 7; param[1] = 8; param[2] = 4;
  param[3] = 3; param[4] = 4;
  ClassifierModule module = new ClassifierModule();
  int r = module.measureRatio(param);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this part -   param[0] = 7; param[1] = 8; param[2] = 4;
  param[3] = 3; param[4] = 4;

Comment: if you don't do that, the array of doubles (param) will be filled with the default value for double, being 0. I just added that to avoid divisionBy0 errors later on

Comment: means[3] / means[1] in your code, with that part I've added will be translated to: 3 / 8

Comment: Won't it change the values that are under the means[3] and means[1]? Both of them contain data from external sensor.

Comment: in your current code, there are no values, I just added this (for this example alone, not to be copied to your code) to avoid them all being zeroes (as default values). EDIT: with your current code, I mean the code you've posted as example here, not the (probably) bigger chunk of code you later on added a link to

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method like it was a method at class level.
You have to create an object of type `ClassifierModule` in order to be able to call the method, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create an object
    ClassifierModule cm = new ClassifierModule();
    // define a parameter to be passed
    double[] values = {3.0, 4.0}; // this is just an example array!
    // and call the method with that parameter
    int r = cm.measureRatio(double[]);
}
```

As an alternative, you could make the method of the `ClassifierModule` a class method by making it `static`:

```
public class ClassifierModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements BufferListener {

    // this is now a method at class level
    public static int measureRatio(double[] means) {
        return (int) (means[3] / means[1]) ;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // define a parameter to be passed
    double[] values = {3.0, 4.0}; // this is just an example array!
    int r = ClassifierModule.measureRatio(values);
}
```

It depends on your requirements what option you should choose.

Comment: Unfortunately none of these has worked. It ends up with the same error :(

Comment: Well, then please edit your question and post the code of the class `ClassifierModule`. May be useful to see the implementation.

Comment: Pasted lnk to whole file ;)

Comment: I have edited the code in my answer to make it fully compilable. You had no value as parameter, just a type (`double[]`). The value has to be defined to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

As not mentioned, one could simply make the method `static` as it does not depend on any state, on any instance object of the class.

```
public static int measureRatio(double[] means){
    return (int) (means[3] / means[1]) ;
}
```

However the class extends and implements things, probably providing some context for evaluation.

```
public class ClassifierModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements BufferListener {
    public ClassifierModule (ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    public int measureRatio(double[] means) {
        // Maybe use: getReactApplicationContext() 
        return (int) (means[3] / means[1]) ;
    }
}
```

Then one would need to do something like:

```
int r = new ClassifierModule(...).measureRatio(double[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do simple modifications

1. Non static methods can not be called by class name.

   ```
   BufferListener {

        public static int measureRatio(double[] means) {
        return (int) (means[3] / means[1]) ;

   }
   ```

   }
2. You are trying to pass a type in second code. Not a double array.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     double[] array= new double[5];
     array[0] = 1; array[1] = 2; array[2] = 3;
     array[3] = 5; array[4] = 4;
     int r = ClassifierModule.measureRatio(array);//array is a double array
   }
   ```

Comment: Ends up with an error: 'error: cannot find symbol
                int r = ClassifierModule.measureRatio(array);
                                                      ^'

Comment: Hey, you need to create an array first. I gave just an idea. Let me edit